# Redirect mobile website using detectmobilebrowser.com

Tags: jquery, redirect, mobile

i am trying to redirect my website to a mobile website of mine, but the redirection is not working.

Its is written in the file that

> jQuery.browser.mobile will be true if the browser is a mobile device

So i used a bit of my logic and created this code as i found nothing on the web related with this to help me and thats the script i am using

```
<script>
    if ( $jQuery.browser.mobile = true ) {
        window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    }
</script>
```

any idea why its not working ? 
thanks alot

Comment: I think you better to use a server side language to detect the device and redirect the user. Because in some cases the user disable javascript on the device. In PHP you can use this class: [detects mobile phone browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi). also you can Google it and find more codes and classes in any languages that you want.

Comment: Nice try selling but i will pass.

Comment: I didn't want to sell you anything. I said you can Google for better functions. and of course i'm not the owner of that script ;) . I'm glad for your that your problem has been solved. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your comparison needs to have double equal signs `==`

Also, you don't reference as `$jQuery.browser.mobile`, just `jQuery.browser.mobile` or `$.browser.mobile`